# Feed RDLC (Local) report report from List (Entity FrameWork)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, report, rdlc

I got myself a `BiningList` Of student (Entity Framework created class).

I just want to feed my `RDLC` report from that instead of using `DataSet` or stored procedures.

This class contains multiple properties like :

```
string Name;
string FamilyName;
string Mid;
DateTime Birth;
...
```

Any one can help me with that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Option 1 - Using designer

1. Open '**Add New Item**' window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>A</kbd> or from '**Project**' menu choose '**Add New Item ...**'.
2. From the window, choose **Report Wizard**
3. In '**Report Wizard**' window, click '**New ...**' button in front of '**Data source**' combo box.
4. Complete '**Data Source Configuration Wizard**'. In first page choose **Object** and click **Next** button, then in the next page, from tree, find your business object and check the checkbox near it and click **Finish** button to close the data source configuration wizard.
5. Complete the '**Report Wizard**'. The business object will be selected as data source of the report, so follow the wizard by click on **Next** and then in '**Arrange Fields**' page, add some files from '**Available fields**' to '**Σ Values**' list by drag and drop. the in next pages '**Choose the layout**' and '**Choose a style**' and click **Finish**.
6. Open a `Form` and from the **Toolbox** put a `Report Viewer` control on the form.
7. Open '**Report Viewer Tasks**' by click on [image: Smart tag icon] and then '**Choose Report**' from combo box. Then a `BindingSource` will be added to the form.
8. Double click on `Form` to handle `Load` event and add this code to the event handler:

   ```
   var data = db.Students.ToList();        
   this.studentBindingSource.DataSource = data;
   this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
   ```

### Option 2 - Using Code

Put a `ReportViewer` control on a form and handle `Load` event of form and write this code:

```
var data = db.Students.ToList();
var reportDataSource1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
reportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet1"; 
reportDataSource1.Value = data;             
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportSample.Report1.rdlc";
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

`reportDataSource1.Name` should be name of `DataSet` in your report definition. To see it, open the report and in Report Data window, under Datasets node see the dataset name.

If you set report using `ReportEmbeddedResource`, then the property should be name of the report in embedded resources. If it starts with default name space of project and continue with folder names if your report is in a folder in solution explorer and at last the name of report.

Comment: Amazing answer dude ! Thanks